# What's the best way to validate the values of a Set in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, set, hashset

Okay, often I'll have a method that returns a Set of some sort.  The problem with unit testing such a method is that there is no guarantee an iteration over the set will always return the items in the same order.

Does anyone have any preferred method of validating a Set?

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your expected values in a Set and then use assertEquals on the expected and actual set.  That works a charm, e.g.

```
Set<String> expected = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("expected", "items"));
...
Set<String> actual = ...;
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Hey, yeah.  I didn't know you could do that.  From the Java 6 AbstractSet javadocs:

Comment: Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Set  interface.

This implementation first checks if the specified object is this set; if so it returns true. Then, it checks if the specified object is a set whose size is identical to the size of this set; if not, it returns false. If so, it returns containsAll((Collection) o).

Comment: containsAll uses contains, and contains uses the .equals method.  For sets of simple pojos, or anything that has a nice .equals method, that's pretty nifty.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two sets are equal, meaning they contain the same items, if they both contain one another

```
Assert.assertTrue(s1.containsAll(s2) && s2.containsAll(s1))
```

There's also [SetUtils.isEqualSet](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/SetUtils.html#isEqualSet-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-)